# Best/Simplest Way to Implement Custom Button on List/Library?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I've removed most of the default elements with the following:

```
<style type="text/css"> #s4-ribbonrow, .ms-cui-topBar2, .s4-notdlg, .s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle, .s4-notdlg noindex, #ms-cui-ribbonTopBars, #s4-titlerow, #s4-pr s4-notdlg s4-titlerowhidetitle, #s4-leftpanel-content {display:none !important;}    .s4-ca{margin-left:0px !important; margin-right:0px !important;} </style>
```

All that I want to add is a simple button like [this](http://jqueryui.com/button/) that takes the user back to the home page. I had something working (kind of), but the css stylesheets were not working. tried using a CEWP (my normal method) and a Page Viewer Web Part (would work, but the dimensions were too large).

just the most basic way to make a nice little button with jQuery.

Here's some more code.. just can't get it to play nicely with SP.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Button - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "input[type=submit], a" )
      .button()
      .click(function( event ) {

      });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- <button></button> -->

<!-- <input type="submit" value="RE Home" /> -->

<a href="http://mysite/default.aspx">RE Home</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want this button to goto a page or display inside a list for each item?

Comment: just want to go to a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok if that's what you want this will do it...

```
<input type=button onClick="parent.location='http://mysite/default.aspx'" value='RE Home'>
```

Although there are several ways to do this but the above should be right...doing this from memory as I'm on my tablet...

Hope this helps

S

Comment: well what the hell - this is so goofy. ok i think i'm learning something here. why are there two references to css stylesheets?

Comment: ok thanks - one last question - how can i get the theme to only apply to the button - not the entire page?

Comment: I think it best to use CSS to control the look of the button if you want to isolate it from the rest of the look and feel.  If you have this working could you mark up the answer? Cheers.